# Retrieving source code of external website chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to extract the source code of an external website to create a chrome extension.

in the popup.html

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/",function(data){
        $('body').text(data);
        });
        });
```

This is to extract the html source code. I added the website in my permissions tag in the manifest file. But there is no output coming. Could any one let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use build-in script in popup.html, instead you have to use external js file(s), see [Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

If it doesn't work still, you should copy your manifest file here.

Comment: I tried splitting into different files, but it still dint work. Copy my manifest file to where?

Comment: ok it started working. I had to download the jquery file to my computer. Cant include an external JS file. THanks :)

Comment: @user1019083 You can have a link to an external js file if its being securley served (https) which your above code is.  You just have to declare the host in the CSP.  Check the page linked to in the answer and pay extra attention to the section titled `Relaxing the default policy`